# Will there be any performance improvement when accessing objects this way in django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm

I have two models which contain ForeignKey from one to another.

```
class M1(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class M2(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(M1, related_name='children')
```

I'm refactoring the code to improve performance.

Will there be any performance difference between these 2 ORM queries.

```
m1 = M1.objects.get(id=1)
children = m1.children.all()
```

and

```
children = M2.objects.filter(parent_id=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will there be any performance difference between these 2 ORM queries?

**Yes**. In the former, you make a query to fetch the `M1` object, and then you construct a `QuerySet` for the second. If you later "consume" the `QuerySet`, then it will thus make two queries.

In the latter you only construct *one* queryset, and thus only make *one* query if you consume the queryset.

If you thus are not interested in the `M1` object, using the latter is better.